# ResponseEntity and JavaScript - how to retrieve custom error message

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, ecmascript-6, httpresponse

I wonder what is the best way to retrieve a message from server (Spring Boot) and display in frontend (Vue JS, ES6).

Backend (its my only approach with success, to pass error message in header, but maybe there is a better solution?):

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getOneReport(@PathVariable Long incidentId) {

...

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    header.set("text", "My custom error message");
    return ResponseEntity.notFound()
            .headers(header)
            .build();
```

Frontend:

```
axios.get(...)
.then(...)
.catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.headers.text);
```

I tried to pass my custom error message from service to client like this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<Object>(
                "My custom error message that I want to display in frontend", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
```

but I don't know how to read that message from my client (ES6/Vue js):

```
.catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error.error);
```

or

```
.catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error.response.data); -> I get Blob {size: 59, type: "text/plain"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried with response.headers?

```
axios.get(...)
   .then(response){
         console.log(response.headers)
      }
   .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error.headers.text);
```

Here the documentation: https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema